# wpf detect clicked event finished without delaying main process

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I need to detect a procedure from a click event has finished without delaying the main wpf process..

**What I don't want**

```
public void click_event(object sender,routedeventargs)
{
        <launch a bunch of threads>
        while(<threads.are alive>);


        <code for what i want to do after threads are done>
}

public void threadtask()
{}
```

**what i just did**

```
 public void click_event()
   {
         foreach(<thread>)
           <give thread task and start() each>
   }
   }
```

but this will not detect when the threads are done.. need help here. Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Your question isn't very clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for two different things. You want the main thread to not be blocked, but you want to do something when the other threads are done (which you have to wait for). Consider starting the threads from a new thread, then let that other thread do the work. Something like this:

```
public void click_event() 
{
    <start new thread>
         <foreach(thread in threads)>
            <do work>
         <join threads>
         <do your work here>
}
```

So all of the work is on a different thread, even the work you want to do afterward. Given that, do you need more than one worker thread anyway?

Comment: works like a charm.. will probabbly upgrade it the start thread to a background worker later..  Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ClickMe.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ClickMe_Click);
    }

    void ClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += (workSender, workE) =>
        {
            string argument = (string)workE.Argument;
            // argument == "Some data"
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        };

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync("Some data");
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResultsTextBlock.Text = "I'm done";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to detect that all threads are done. not just one.

Comment: Are all your threads doing the same thing (execute the same method) or do they have different tasks? You can start a count and decrement the count each thread that finish and check for count == 0, or if they do a different thing you can set an enum flag. Or if you implement producer/consumer, create an object that gets filled with the thread's results and check the object for completion.